# Outlook 2007 completely ignores width and height for elements in table cell

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I’m going through the horror of trying to make HTML e-mail templates that look acceptable in Outlook, and quickly nearing the point of hara-kiri.

I have a basic table setup: three columns, with all content in the middle one. The columns on the side are just there to give spacing. The table has a `width` of 100% so it takes up the entire width of the reading window. So essentially this (with all the Outlook-specific crud left out):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftsidespacer"></td>
            <td class="maincontent">
                <p>All the content here</p>
                <div class="thisisabox">
                    <p>Something here too</p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="rightsidespacer"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In any normal e-mail client, this is a piece of cake. You set a width on the middle column and that’s pretty much it. Outlook 2007 (and probably other versions) instead collapses all three columns so the middle column takes up 100% of the body width. Basically, setting a width on a table cell has no effect.

All right, so I fall back on *really* old-time ways of adding an image in the empty cells to force them to have some width. Ugly and stupid, but at least it sorta-kinda works.

The problem I’m facing now, which I mysteriously cannot find *anyone* even mentioning online, is that any element that I put inside a `td` **always ends up being 100% of the width of the cell and the height of the content**, no matter what I do.

The `div` with the class `thisisabox` in the example above, for example, always ends up being just one line of text in height and 100% of the table cell, even if I define it thus:

```
<div width="200" height="200"
    style="display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;">
```

Everything in me screams that this should produce a 200 × 200 pixel red box, but it doesn’t. It just gets ignored completely.

As far as I can tell, there is nothing in my styles which ought to have any influence on this. The entirety of the styles declarations I have for the bits in the HTML snippet above is this:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table, tr, td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    padding: 35px 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

(It gets inlined and HTML-attributified by the [Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca) API before sending, so it’s not because the styles are only declared in the `head`.)

### Is there some way of making Outlook notice specified width and height of elements inside a table cell?

Or am I missing something really obvious that’s making Outlook behave in this infuriating way?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not work with `div` and it in some instances ignores `padding`.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/padding/

The way to fix this is simple and it will work with every email client:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>

<table width="200" height="200" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="leftsidespacer" width="30"></td>
        <td class="maincontent" width="140">
            <p>All the content here</p>
            <div class="thisisabox">
                <p>Something here too</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="rightsidespacer" width="30"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I would create a style sheet and add the values which will be picked up by most modern email clients, but Outlook desktop versions like 2007-2016 require a few inline aids to function properly.

**Edit: Base table in Outlook 2007**

This is the base table in Outlook 2007 with no extra css that I posted above:

[image: Outlook 2007 Base Table]

This image came out of Litmus.

I only used the code I posted above. If you are not seeing this, something in your CSS or HTML is causing an issue.

Good luck.

Comment: Outlook 2007 doesn’t generally ignore padding (though it does seem to quite consistently ignore margin declarations), no. The paddings on the `td` elements here works fine. The trouble I’m having is that it doesn’t matter whether the element inside the cell is a div or something else—its declared width and height are uniformly ignored. Your example here does something different (makes the whole containing table 200×200 rather than the box inside the cell), but even nesting a table doesn’t work either: the table’s width becomes 100% of the containing cell.

Comment: I posted my code I ran in Litmus for Outlook 2007 and posted an image of the result in my answer. I truly understand the frustration that is Outlook. I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh and @JanusBahsJacquet, unrelated, but great answer on Shelob. She truly is nobody's pet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try.

**Code:**

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="200" height="200" bgcolor="#000000">
<tbody>
    <tr>
 <td height="200"></td>
        <td valign="top" style="color:#ffffff;">
            All content here

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Result in Outlook version 1803 (tested: 20/04/2018)**

[image]

What I have done is added a height to the table element as well as one of the cells. You can either populate the left column with a spacer image or keep it as it is.

**Note:** You can make do without the left column if you wish but do add the height

Hope this is the answer you were looking for.